# JavaScript for font changer

Tags: javascript, fonts

Does anyone know the JavaScript needed to make a simple font changer? 
I would like to have a small popup window on a page that when you select a font it changes the font of all the text areas on another page. I would like it to change text already on the page but it does not have to. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JQuery? That would help a lot, there are several relatively simple ways to do this

Comment: jQuery isnt necessary for it. All modern browsers could do this naively

Comment: use a class switcher and pre-defined css classes for the body tag. eg:  body.mono * { font-family: monopsace;} ... <button onclick='(opener||self).document.body.className="mono"; '>monospace</button>

Comment: @cgatian I didn't say it was necessary

Comment: Then I would argue that jQuery doesnt help.

Comment: I just came back and looked at this... It makes me cry. Should have definitely been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method would be to define a number of classes, each which have the font.

```
.arial { font-family: Arial; }
.times { font-family: "Times New Roman"; }
```

Then, create a select or something which can trigger the events. We'll put the class names in the value parameter of the options:

```
<select id="font-changer">
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="times">Times</option>
</select>
```

Then, add an event to change the class of whatever element you are targeting to the predefined class name. In this case, we'll assume we are changing the body:

```
document.getElementById('font-changer').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.body.className = this.value;
});
```

And that's it. Here is a simple JSFiddle which targets a paragraph element with the ID of "target": http://jsfiddle.net/48dh9/

If the target element needs to have other classes besides the fonts, you need to make sure you remove the font class (doable by looping through all the options of the select and checking if the target element has any of those classes and removing them) and then add the class (so `className += " " + this.value` instead of just `className = this.value`), but you said simple, so... ;)

Comment: Damn you beat me to it.

Comment: I would also note if they are supporting IE10+ they can use  classList to add a new class and not have to worry about string concatination, and it performs faster because setting each class won't cause animation frame to occur. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Comment: classList is good, though realistically you should still be supporting at least IE9+ in 99% of cases. Hopefully we can switch that to only IE10+. Though, if you wanted to use that and provide a fallback, that works as well.

Comment: Thanks! That's what i wanted.